# Python : initializing list and dictionary

Tags: python

I am new to Python. while initializing a list

```
mylist = list()
mylist[0]="hello"
```

gives error .It only works

```
mylist.append("hello")
```

but if i do same with dictionary

```
mydict ={}
mydict["one"]="hello"
```

it works.
why i dont need to do

```
mydict['one'].append('hello')
```

why things are different for different structures.

Comment: list() creates an empty list, so there is no element 0 to access

Comment: you can create list with initial values like this: `mylist = ['hello']`

Comment: What i mean to ask is when list is created it has no values and we cant add values using the index. But when directories are created we can add values to it using keys .we dont need append method.why is this so

Comment: @Goyo `mylist[0]` also won't work because it's an empty list so you can't index it

Comment: @user2779311 As you noticed they are different structures with different associated operations and behavior.

Comment: I dont really understand the downvotes on this, its a very basic question but legit nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

If you update a dict like this:

```
d['c'] = 3
```

... there is no need for `d['a']` and `d['b']` (or any item at all, for that matter) to be present in that dict. The key of a dictionary item does not imply any specific structural properties of your dict object.

However, if you want to update a list like this:

```
l[5] = 'a'
```

... the indexes 0 through 5 absolutely must exist. The index not only serves as a handle for an element in the list, but also has structural properties. If `l[5]` does exist, you can be absolutely sure that indexes 0 through 4 do as well. And you need that certainty.

Imagine you could do `l[5] = 'a'` on an empty list. What would `len(l)` return? 1? 6?
Both cases would cause this to fail:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i])
```

One can argue that `l[<index>] = 'a'` *could* implicitly append that value if index-1 already exists or if the list is empty and the desired index is 0. In order for this to reliably work, you would need to *ensure* that index-1 exists before adding values like this, while, when using append(), you are guaranteed that your value will be added to the list (except for potential edge cases like memory starvation).

Answer (score 0):

If you add an element to a dictionary you connect to a key.
In your case you connect the element `'hello'` to your key `'one'`

To add an element to a list you will have to use the function `list.append`.
You use `list[x]` to get the element at position x.